# Causal Mediation using "mediation" library

Tags: r, percentage, negative-number

I am new to this so please excuse my ineptness. 
I am trying to do a causal mediation using the "mediation" library. 
I have two questions.

1. I know that the results should be as a proportion, but I am getting whole numbers, so am not sure how that can happen, what it means, or what to do about it.
2. All the outputs are negative. I can see from previous questions that if one output is negative, that helps explain what is going on. But if both are negative?

Thank you for your assistance.

**Below is the code and the output.**

```
> set.seed(123)
> med.fit<-lm(FCItotal ~ Group + AgeYearsChecked + Sex, data = gtrF)
> out.fit <-lm(HHSTotal ~ FCItotal + Group + AgeYearsChecked + Sex, data = gtrF)
> med.FCI<-mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat="Group", mediator="FCItotal", robustSE=TRUE, sims=1000)
> summary(med.FCI)

Causal Mediation Analysis 

Quasi-Bayesian Confidence Intervals

               Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME            -3.7338      -9.5643         1.08    0.12    
ADE             -9.7899     -16.1793        -3.29  <2e-16 ***
Total Effect   -13.5236     -19.3789        -7.75  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated   0.2659      -0.0818         0.68    0.12    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Sample Size Used: 65 


Simulations: 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, I am a bit embarrassed. I can see that my only problem is misreading the data table. The Prop. Mediated is the number I am after, not the whole numbers.